# Increase performance of INNER JOIN with subquery

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

Is there any way for optimizing the below query without further addition of any INDEX, if possible?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VFUN_Late_Evnt_By_Acct_Doc_Id]
AS
SELECT 
     L.Doc_Id
    ,L.Evnt_Id as Latest_Event_Id
    ,E.Evnt_Name as Latest_Event_Name
    ,L.Crtd_Dt
    ,L.Evnt_Xml_Doc as Latest_Event_xml
    ,L.IsMailSent 
FROM TFUN_Intg_Log L
    INNER JOIN TFUN_Intg_Evnt E
    ON L.Evnt_Id = E.Evnt_Id
    INNER JOIN (Select Doc_Id, Max(Crtd_Dt) AS Crtd_Dt From TFUN_Intg_Log
                Group by Doc_Id) M 
    ON M.Doc_Id = L.Doc_Id AND M.Crtd_Dt = L.Crtd_Dt
```

Also, I have this clustered index on the table `TFUN_Intg_Log`:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TFUN_Intg_Log] ADD  CONSTRAINT [XFUN_Intg_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Intg_Log_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: And once that's fixed maybe include some more information on the table(s), fields and so on, as such it's pretty unclear what this is about.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are just trying to get only Max(Crtd_Dt) and going the long way to get there

```
SELECT L.Doc_Id
     , L.Evnt_Id      as Latest_Event_Id
     , E.Evnt_Name    as Latest_Event_Name
     , L.Crtd_Dt
     , L.Evnt_Xml_Doc as Latest_Event_xml
     , L.IsMailSent 
FROM TFUN_Intg_Log  L
JOIN TFUN_Intg_Evnt E
      ON E.Evnt_Id = L.Evnt_Id
JOIN ( Select Doc_Id, Max(Crtd_Dt) AS Crtd_Dt 
       From TFUN_Intg_Log
       Group by Doc_Id 
     ) M 
      ON M.Doc_Id  = L.Doc_Id 
     AND M.Crtd_Dt = L.Crtd_Dt
```

[Row_number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is a more direct and efficient route

```
select * from 
( SELECT L.Doc_Id
       , L.Evnt_Id      as Latest_Event_Id
       , E.Evnt_Name    as Latest_Event_Name
       , L.Crtd_Dt
       , L.Evnt_Xml_Doc as Latest_Event_xml
       , L.IsMailSent 
       , row_number() over (partition by L.Evnt_Id order by L.Crtd_Dt desc) as rn
  FROM TFUN_Intg_Log  L
  JOIN TFUN_Intg_Evnt E
        ON E.Evnt_Id = L.Evnt_Id 
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: Do you care to add a description or why this is a good answer to OPs question?

Comment: @Vogel612 Yes I have provided an explanation.  As stated row_number is more direct and efficient route to that information.